# What is this Big File in public_html - zikIq8Eq 19.65 GB - text/x-generic 0600

Tags: magento2

Hello I have this Text Generic with 0600 permissions and it takes too much space . File is zikIq8Eq 19.65 GB - text/x-generic 0600
What is it and can i delete it ?
Thanks

Comment: do you have ssh root user access?

Comment: Yes  i have sssh

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted , Everything is fine .